# How does JMeter looping work?

Tags: jmeter

Are the simulation loops separate? With separate I mean that JMeter waits for all threads to be done to begin a new iteration of the loop. Or does JMeter just let every thread do a request X time, without stopping?

Additional question: Could one change the number of threads dynamically? Doing a simulation for a range of number of thread (e.g. 100-1500) would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each thread is completely independent. So when you have loop set, if a thread is finished its first loop of execution, it goes for another round (as per the loop count) irrespective of the completion of other threads.

You can use a variable for the number of threads & set the number via property files etc. But when the test is running, you can not change the no of threads for the test.

Hope it is clear!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Is it possible to completely separate the iterations?

Comment: Hi, Can you please provide more info of what you are trying to do.?

Comment: I want to send 5000 requests at the same time to a particular server and do this test 40 times. The tests should be separate, so every thread should be finished before the next iteration of the loop can begin.

Comment: I see. So number of threads should be 5000 as you know already. You need to use "Synchronizing Timer" in your test. Set the number of users in it. This timer will make a thread wait for all the threads (mentioned in the timer) to be ready. Once it is ready, it will send all the requests at the same time to the server.

Comment: It works! Thanks.
Just having some problems with my massive amount of threads (at about 2000 threads JMeter can't create threads anymore), but other than providing the argument -xMX there's no way to solve that right?

Comment: Hi Arthur, 5000 threads seem to be really too much. Check this.
Looks like you can upito 600 per machine. 
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Comment: Yes, ca. 1900 seems the limit. 600 is really low... The reference mentions "The exception is the webservices". I ran a test with 1800 threads without being at 100% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [vIns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897008/vins) answer:

You **CAN** change load dynamically during execution. Threads count is static, but their fire rate is something you can impact.

Look into combination of [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) and [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).